# Select all spaces except those in a group

Tags: regex

If I have the following text:

> `This is a sample sentence containing "quotes with spaces in them" for regex texting. Here is "another" quote.`

I want to select every space in the text EXCEPT those in the quotes.

I have a regex group (`("[\w^\s]*")`) matching the quotes, but I can't figure out how to tell the regex to IGNORE everything in there.

Sublime text says that `^("[\w^\s]*")` is invalid, and I don't know what else I can do.

I've also tried `(?:"[\w^\s]*")` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: And what do you want to do with these spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$) +
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bO5zT6)

assuming there is no escaping exceptions.

Comment: Unfortunately this includes the entire double quote string.

Comment: Thanks, it matches spaces only if those are outside quotes by making sure there are even number of quotes after space.